# Read one line at time from a file when a function is called each time

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

```
String time=Read_one_Line();

public static String Read_one_Line() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{

  FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("sample.txt");

  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));

  str=br.readLine();

  next_line=br.readLine();

  return next_line;
}
```

**Each time it should read one line from text file** called **"sample.txt"** and **return it**. next time it should return next line and so on....

**Contents of sample.txt are:**

```
Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:310

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:10

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:380

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:10  MilliSeconds:-840

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0

Date:0   Year:0  Hour:0  Minute:0    Seconds:0   MilliSeconds:0
```

But rather its reading and returning first line only each time.. please tell me how to increment to next line and return it when i call this function next time.

Comment: Please, don't change your question to a completely new one. This makes the answer(s) not match the question and someone who later reads this question+answer will only be confused. If you have a new question, well, do create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `FileInputStream` each time the function is called. Therefore, the file is read from the beginning each time.

Create the `BufferedReader` only once, outside of the function and pass it in on each call, so that the file is successively read.

```
public static String Read_one_Line(final BufferedReader br) throws IOException
{
  next_line=br.readLine();

  return next_line;
}
```

usage would be like

```
static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

  FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("sample.txt");

  try {

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));

    String line = Read_one_Line(br);
    while ( line != null ) {
      System.out.println(line);
      line = Read_one_Line(br);
    }

  } finally {
    fin.close(); // Make sure we close the file when we're done.
  }
}
```

Note that in this case, `Read_one_Line` could just be omitted and replaced by a simple `br.readLine()`.

If you only want every other line, you can just read two lines in each iteration, like

```
String line = Read_one_Line(br);
while ( line != null ) {
  System.out.println(line);
  String dummy = Read_one_Line(br);
  line = Read_one_Line(br);
}
```

Comment: Thank you..Good Effort !