# Searching for specific data in file using StreamReader C# then writing it to console window

Tags: c#, search, streamreader

I come to you with as I have exhausted myself searching Google and trying my own methods.

I have a struct made up of all strings which are stored in a text file. I want the user to be able to search for customer accounts in the text file by the customer's number and then the program should then return the customer information.

Below is the non-working search method I have created for the program. I get to the stage of this method as it allows me to enter the customer's number I want to search but after I press enter, I get nothing in return:

If you could tell me what is wrong in this code I'll be extremely grateful and relieved!

```
        //SEARCHING BY CUSTOMER NUMBER

    static void FindCustNo(CustomerStruct[] CustomerDeats)
    {
        String NumberSearch;
        bool CustomerNumberMatch = false;
        Console.Clear();

    begin:
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tPlease enter a customer number: ");
            NumberSearch = Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed. Please try again.");
            goto begin;
        }


        while (!CustomerNumberMatch)
        {
            var pathToCust = @"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt";

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToCust))
            {
                RecCount = 0;

                CustomerDeats[RecCount].CustomerNo = sr.ReadLine();                                   


                if (CustomerDeats[RecCount].CustomerNo == NumberSearch)
                    {
                        CustomerNumberMatch = true;

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].CustomerNo = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].CustomerNo);

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].Surname = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].Surname);

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].Forename = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].Forename);

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].Street = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].Town);

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].Town = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].Town);

                        CustomerDeats[RecCount].DOB = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerDeats[RecCount].DOB);  
                    }

                   RecCount++;   

                if (RecCount > 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No One Found");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();           
    }
```

Comment: have you tried debugging and watched what happens? What goes wrong etc?

Comment: Take a look at your struct, find one that has a customer number that is in the file. Type that number in the console and debug. What happens when it iterates over the line that should match it?

Comment: @aeliusd Unfortunately I'm relatively new to programming, when I do a 'master' debug there are no errors. That's the height of my debugging skills. Not that familiar with breakpoints, especially with making sense of the results they return.

Comment: Why cant you post your Data file sample? without looking into file it is difficult to find answer from not working code.

Comment: It magically worked when ever I inserted breakpoints, Im even more confused now

Comment: Ill edit the post and post the data file.

Comment: Fine... You are doing ReadLine for every field. Thats the issue. once you found the record, do not call ReadLine... ReadLine returns one customers all the field. Also please load into Array as I mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while (!CustomerNumberMatch)
    {
        var pathToCust = @"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt";

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToCust))

        ...
```

Seems to be the same problem someone else had just [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059122/read-one-line-at-time-from-a-file-when-a-function-is-called-each-time/23059220#23059220):

Why do you create a new `StreamReader` in every iteration?

Try this:

```
    var pathToCust = @"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToCust) {

        while (!CustomerNumberMatch)
        { 
            ...
```

Comment: Good :) -- The reason it did not work was that every time after one line was read from the `StreamReader` a new `StreamReader` was created which would read the file from the beginning again. Thus, you'd always and repeatedly read only the first line of the file again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to find in Array instead of file. Following lines of code will return Array of string from file

```
 string[] records = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filePath");
 foreach (var record in records)
   {
      string[] fields = record.Split(' ');//space
      if (customerIdToFind == fields[0])
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Customer ID:" + fields[0]);
          Console.WriteLine("Customer Name:" + fields[1]);
        }
    }
```

**Do not do this for large file**, it will load entire content to memory. so StreamReader is always good.

Comment: @CreativeManix: What makes you think the OP has all fields of each customer in a single line, separated by spaces?

Comment: @Hanno Binder, I asked that as a comment in the question. Asker also added the Sample Data... Looks like now the question is edited and the Sample data is removed :).

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't see there had been sample data. In that case, your answer is of course correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
                int size, string filePath);
 /// <summary>
        /// read value from given section and key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Section">string</param>
        /// <param name="Key">string</param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
 public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                            255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();

        }
```

To call this function See Below Code

```
string sBENCHNO = ini.IniReadValue("Sextion", "Key");
```